# windbg disassembly search and bp inconsistent

Tags: windbg, disassembly

I used windbg's `#` command to search for the literal 2f7e appearing in WININET's dissasembly. Here's one it found:

```
0:000> # 2f7e 000007fefde50000+1000
[...snip...]
0:000> # 2f7e
WININET!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpSendRequest_Finish+0x151:
000007fe`fdf0e54d 41be7e2f0000    mov     r14d,2F7Eh
```

So the address of the instruction is 000007fe`fdf0e54d. But when I set a breakpoint using the symbol+offset, I get a different breakpoint address (see breakpoint 1):

```
0:002> bp WININET!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpSendRequest_Finish+0x151
0:002> bl
 0 e 00000001`3f920124     0001 (0001)  0:**** foo!bar
 1 e 000007fe`fde70ef1     0001 (0001)  0:**** WININET!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpSendRequest_Start+0x744
```

So breakpoint 1 is not for the instruction I found with `#`:

```
0:002> u 000007fe`fde70ef1 l1
WININET!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpSendRequest_Start+0x744:
000007fe`fde70ef1 0f846d6a0000    je      WININET!HTTP_REQUEST_HANDLE_OBJECT::HttpSendRequest_Start+0x80e (000007fe`fde77964)
```

Any ideas as to why `#` and `bp` resolve the same symbolic name+offset to different addresses?

thanks

Comment: Aside: So what's the WININET problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Some code of ours is using the URLDownloadToFile API which internally calls into WinINet which is failing. While stepping through the debugger I noticed some call in WinINet results in `!gle` reporting 0x2f7e as the LastErrorValue. So I wanted to find any instructions in WinINet that have that literal as an operand. The thinking is the failure happens near that instruction.

Comment: FYI, WININET comes in [a debug version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/884931), which has tracing capabilities built in that have helped me troubleshoot issues like this in the past.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Good to know, thanks! Turns out WinINet was calling CreateFile but one of the folders in the path was marked "DELETE PENDING" so CreateFile was failing the operation with ACCESS_DENIED but then WinINet translated that error code to 0x2f7e (0n12158) which is ERROR_INTERNET_UNABLE_TO_CACHE_FILE. URLDownloadToFile translated that to 0x800c0008 which is ERROR_INTERNET_UNABLE_TO_CACHE_FILE. My procmon filter was too strict otherwise I would have seen the original ACCESS_DENIED so I ended up spelunking through some disassembly. Good stuff!

Comment: @Marc: it seems you have found the answer. Maybe you can post it as an answer and then mark is as solved 2 days later. Otherwise people like me will try to answer old questions and find "false positives" (questions which are already solved but marked as unsolved in the SO search). Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas If you're referring to my comment, then I would have to say that it doesn't answer the original question.